# Floating point operation/arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, floating-point

I read my lecture script and I have a question regarding this statement.

"The approximation using floating point numbers with fixed mantissa length is useful, because the cost of each floating point operation (for ex. round(round(x)+round(y)) does not depend on $x$, $y$ but on the mantissa length".

A relevant example would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: How do you think an example could be relevant? Did you mean the micro-algorithm that implements the addition? In short, bringing both operands to the same exponent and carrying out the mantissa addition has a fixed cost, independent of the exponents. One could then mention how the FPU and multi-precision variants are essentially the same,...

Comment: one way to do it is reverse the number and carry backwards to normal, figure out the places after. $4562951413+4562951413=8035813826$ meaning $2\pi\approx 6.283185308$